# find prime numbers including and between two numbers using

Tags: c, function

I need to find prime numbers between and including two numbers, using functions.
For example, with <<(3 23)>> the output is 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23

This is my code so far, but I’m having troubles with it. What am I doing wrong or how can I improve my solution?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check_prime(int l,int u){
    int x, i;

    for (x = l; x <= u; x++){
        for (i = 2; i < x; i++){
            if (x % i == 0) break;
        }
    }
    if (i == x) return x;
}

int main(){
    int x, y, f;
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    f = check_prime(x, y);
    printf("%d", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you want to print all prime numbers between `l` and `u` you must do the check `x == i` inside the loop from `l` to `u`. At the moment, you return a single value (but only if `i==x`; you should return a useful value for all paths through the function) and print that.

Comment: print prime numbers between two numbers a and b including a and b

Comment: ex >between [3 and 23 ] 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the value returned from `check_prime()` and that will be one value only. If you want to print all the prime numbers in a range, i suggest instead of returning value from `check_prime()` you print the value in that function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void check_prime(int l,int u){
  int x,i;

  for(x=l;x<=u;x++){
    for(i=2;i<x;i++){
      if(x%i==0)
        break;
    }
    if(i==x){
      printf("%d ", x);
    }
  }

}

int main(){
  int x,y;
  scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
  check_prime(x,y);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the executable code: https://repl.it/@fiveelements/PrintPrimeNumbersInARange?language=c

Comment: IT CLEARED ALL MY DOUBTS ABOUT 4 TYPES OF FUCTIONS .